# Java RMI adding numbers

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-system

I am trying to learn how RMI works in Java (complete beginner at RMI) and I have been looking at some examples which show how to add two numbers together. The problem is that I always use netbeans (and want to continue doing so) and all the examples are Java from command line. Does anybody know how to do such a small application from netbeans? (i'm using build 6) Thanks very much in advance :) The tutorial i've been looking at is: http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/mes/courses/cps530/programs/rmi/Schildt/addTwoNumbers.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run two pieces: one for the server and another for the client.  You'll start the RMI server and let it listen for requests, then run the client and interact with the server.

NetBeans will have to be able to run two applications inside it.  I'm sure it's possible if you look at it properly.  You'll just have to be sure to package the code in such a way that there's server, client, and common classes.